# Rotating the text in bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to do a vertical bar chart with its corresponding values inside each bar(they are huge number). so i want to rotate each text by -90 degrees, so that they align in bars.The problem is, i am not able to set an different origin for each text so that i can rotate them independently.all the text elements are having a common origin and rotating as if they are kept on line like shown in the image.how to generate different origins in for each text?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu6W6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like code below. Look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ccdcb7673cdb3a796e13). Post your code on plnkr if this doesn't work for you may be I can take a look.

```
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis)
 .selectAll("text") 
 .style("text-anchor", "end")
 .attr("dx", "-.8em")
 .attr("dy", ".15em")
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "rotate(-65)" 
  });
```